# Meaning of merge, phi, effectphi and dead in v8 terminology

Tags: v8, jit

I’m trying to read the v8 source code (in particular the compiler part of it) to understand better the optimisation and reduction procedures (in order to look for bugs).

I ran into a few terms that are used in the comments but seem to be unexplained. The comment is this:

```
 // Check if this is a merge that belongs to an unused diamond, which means
 // that:
 //
 //  a) the {Merge} has no {Phi} or {EffectPhi} uses, and
 //  b) the {Merge} has two inputs, one {IfTrue} and one {IfFalse}, which are
 //     both owned by the Merge, and
 //  c) and the {IfTrue} and {IfFalse} nodes point to the same {Branch}.
```

What do the terms Merge, Phi and EffectPhi mean? Also, does marking a node as “dead” mean that it will treated as redundant?

Thanks in advance.

The link to the above code is this:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git/+/refs/heads/master/src/compiler/common-operator-reducer.cc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

V8 developer here. As background knowledge, it helps to know that V8's "Turbofan" compiler uses the "SSA" (static single assignment) and "sea of nodes" concepts. There are various compiler textbooks and research papers that explain these in great detail. To answer your questions in short:

A "Merge" node merges two control nodes, i.e. two branches of control flow. You can think of it as the "opposite" of a Branch, or the equivalent of a Phi for control nodes. Control nodes are the mechanism that Turbofan's sea-of-nodes design uses to make sure nodes aren't reordered across certain control flow boundaries.

A "Phi" node merges the two (or more) possibilities for a value that have been computed by different branches. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form for more.

An "EffectPhi" is a special version of a Phi node that's used for nodes on the "effect chain". The effect chain is the mechanism Turbofan uses to make sure that nodes' external effects (like memory loads and stores) aren't visibly reordered.

A "dead" node is one that's unreachable and can be eliminated. So it's "redundant" in the sense of "superfluous/unnecessary", but not in the sense of "the same as another node".