# What is the meaning of the 'Dead' Turbofan operator?

Tags: javascript, v8, jit

I thought it meant unreachable or dead code following common programming terms.

However, I found TurboFan builds IR like the one below while optimizing. Below code is summarized parts of sea-of-nodes IR which is originally represented by graph form.

```
#47:Dead()
#50:IfTrue(#47:Dead)
#48:IfFalse(#47:Dead)
#51:Merge(#50:IfTrue, #48:IfFalse)
#52:Return(#51:Merge)
#53:End(#52:Return)
```

If 'Dead' means unreachable, it is weird that it connects to the 'End'. What are the exact meaning and use of the 'Dead' operator?

```
function main() {
  function v0(){}
function v0(v1,v2) {
    const v4 = -1.7976931348623157e+308 + v1;
    const v5 = v2 >= v1;
    if (v5) {
        const v7 = 2784663676 >= 2784663676;
        if (v7) {
            const v8 = ++v1;
        } else {
            const v9 = v2 ^ -1.7976931348623157e+308;
        }
    } else {
        const v10 = -1.7976931348623157e+308 > -1.7976931348623157e+308;
    }
    if (v5) {
        return -128;
        const v12 = v2 >= v1;
        let v13 = v5 ? v2 : v1;
        const v14 = v13 > -128;
        const v15 = v14 ? v13 : -128;
        const v16 = --v13;
    } else {
        const v17 = v2 < v2;
        const v18 = 770699.7300170623;
        const v19 = v1 * v1;
        const v20 = -536870912;
        const v21 = v17 ? v2 : v2;
    }
}
for(var i=0;i<50000;i++){
    const v17 = v0(1.5,-0.0);
  }
}
%NeverOptimizeFunction(main);
main();
```

This is the JS code input that I used.

Comment: Can you post some example input JS that results in that V8/TurboFan output?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57463700/meaning-of-merge-phi-effectphi-and-dead-in-v8-terminology

Comment: @Dai I uploaded JS input file, thanks! I already read the attached link, but it is still unclear if 'Dead' is unreachable, I think it shouldn't connect to 'End'.